# Changing Android locale works in debug version of app, but only updates to English or Spanish in release version, no other Locales work

Tags: android, localization, google-play, locale, release

So I wanted to create a way for a user to change between 6 different languages within my Android app. Currently, I have string resource files for English (default), Spanish, German, French, Japanese, and Russian. When I run the code on my emulator, or on my phone through debug, everything works perfectly. The app updates when I select a language, and runs great.

However, when I change to the release version, generate a signed app bundle and upload it to the play store for internal testing, and I download the app from there, the only language options that work is English and Spanish. All my other language options revert to English, despite my logs stating that the locale of the configuration properly changed to the specific locale I want.

My guess is that maybe there's some sort of phone specific setting that's preventing me from seeing the additional languages? But I'm unsure how to work around that, and I'm also confused why, if that's the case, Spanish would be working but no other languages.

Here is the OnClick that sets the locale and calls my UpdateLocale method (These correspond to buttons I've added within an alert dialog box for language selection):

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    switch (which) {
        case 0:
            Locale usLocale = new Locale("en");
            editor.putString("Locale", "en");
            editor.apply();
            updateLocale(usLocale);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;// english
        case 1:
            Locale esLocale = new Locale("es");
            editor.putString("Locale", "es");
            editor.apply();
            updateLocale(esLocale);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;// spanish
        case 2:
            Locale deLocale = new Locale("de");
            editor.putString("Locale", "de");
            editor.apply();
            updateLocale(deLocale);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;// german
        case 3:
            Locale frLocale = new Locale("fr");
            editor.putString("Locale", "fr");
            editor.apply();
            updateLocale(frLocale);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;// french
        case 4:
            Locale jaLocale = new Locale("ja");
            editor.putString("Locale", "ja");
            editor.apply();
            updateLocale(jaLocale);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;// japanese
        case 5:
            Locale ruLocale = new Locale("ru");
            editor.putString("Locale", "ru");
            editor.apply();
            updateLocale(ruLocale);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;// russian
    }
    recreate();
}
```

And here is the UpdateLocale method itself:

```
public void updateLocale(Locale locale) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();

    if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 24) {
        LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);

        LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
        configuration.setLocales(localeList);
        configuration.setLocale(locale);

    } else if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 17){
        configuration.setLocale(locale);

    } else {
        configuration.locale = locale;
    }

    res.updateConfiguration(configuration, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

I have already added the locales I want to my build.gradle file

```
resConfigs "en", "de", "es", "fr", "ja", "ru"
```

And I have added the following to all activities within my android manifest

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

If anyone knows what I might be doing wrong, or what I might be able to look for to figure out why there's a disconnect between my Debug and Release versions, I'd be eternally grateful.

After some cursory googling, I've tried checking the libraries I'm using to see if I need to add anything to the proguard-rules.pro file, as that has rules that get applied when you generate a release version of an app, however none of the libraries I'm using are being used in this specific context to change the locale, so I don't think that's my problem.

Answer (score 2):

After someone pointed me towards language-splitting within App Bundles, I figured out my issue. When you generate an app-bundle, it, by default, will split the bundle by language, and only download whatever language is needed by the user's device, and no others.

This is easily solved by adding the following within the Android section of the apps build.gradle file:

```
bundle {
    language {
        enableSplit = false
    }
}
```